# Show div if another is div is present on page

Tags: jquery, visibility

I'm attempting to include 2 layouts within a shopping cart based on attributes of a product. If the product contains div A then I want to show extra options on the page that are in a different area and div. if div a is not present I'll keep the extra div hidden. I'm not sure how to handle this in jquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `length` property to check whether or not an element exists like this:

```
if ($('#divID').length > 0){
  // div with id divID is present 
}
else{
  // div with id divID is NOT present
}
```

Comment: `If the product contains div A` - I think it should be checking if a child or an element is inside a given element. And not just checking `$('#divID')` if it exist. Cause it might exist, but not inside. :)

Comment: @:Reigel: True but you can check for its existence directly too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the existence of an element you can get the length and then check if its greater than 0.

```
if ($("#divID").length > 0) {
    // your element exists
}
```

If you want to check the visibility then you can go for `.is(":visible")`

```
if ($("#divID").is(":visible")) {
    // your element is visible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#product div.A').length > 0) {
    $('div.otherDiv').show()
}
```

that is if you have this kind of html or similar,

```
<div id="product">

 <div class="A"></div>

</div>
```